# After inputting the ordered data set into Optaplanner, why is the optimized result worse?

Tags: java, optaplanner

The model is modeled with reference to the tsp problem, and several hard constraints are established with Drools. Originally, I wanted to use Optaplanner to score the production plan (input ordered data set) and optimize the plan to get a better plan. After I entered the plan, I used ScoreManager to evaluate the score before it was solved and only 5 violations of the hard constraints . But when I joined the sover program to optimize the solution, the results showed that there were more violations of the hard constraints. The final output sequence is not as good as the initial sequence. Shouldn’t the ideal situation be that there are fewer constraint violations of the output result? What is the situation?

Comment: That is indeed strange. I recommend you run your solver with <environmentMode>FULL_ASSERT</> - I bet you will find that you will see score corruptions. That would mean that your constraints are doing something they should not; and we'd have to look into that instead.

Comment: Does this problem have anything to do with the choice of algorithm? I configured the same FIRST_FIT_DECREASING algorithm as the tsp example.
My goal is to optimize the input plan (ordered data) through the restriction of hard constraints, that is, to reduce the violation of hard constraints. Which algorithm should I choose?

Comment: No, that should be unrelated. If you have a score corruption in your constraints, it will show no matter which local search variant you use.